# How to show last 20 tweets with twitter api on express.js with node.js?

Tags: javascript, api, express, twitter

I want use Twitter API (https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) and here are the thinks I'd like to add:

app.js & package.json

```
var express = require("express"),
path        = require("path"),
http        = require("http"),
twitter     = require("twitter"),
app         = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

twitter_data.js

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: '',
  consumer_secret: '',
  access_token_key: '',
  access_token_secret: ''
});

var params = {screen_name: 'nodejs'};

client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response){
  if (!error) {
    console.log(tweets);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll try to keep it short, here we go:

Install [express-generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html) module first: `npm install -g express-generator`

Run `express --hbs` (you can choose Jade or anything else, but I prefer Handlebars, so I'll continue with that)

Go to the folder and install dependencies: `npm install`

Install [twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) module: `npm install --save twitter`

Go to Twitter's [Application Management Page](https://apps.twitter.com/) and create your app. Get the necessary keys: consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, and access_token_secret.

After this point, I'd like to share the actual codes instead of explaining what to do

Here's /routes/index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var router = express.Router(); 
var client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'XXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXX',
  access_token_key: 'XXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXX'
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline
  client.get('statuses/user_timeline', { screen_name: 'nodejs', count: 20 }, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if (!error) {
      res.status(200).render('index', { title: 'Express', tweets: tweets });
    }
    else {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here's /views/index.hbs file:

```
<ul>
  {{#each tweets }}
  <li>{{ this.text }}</li>
  {{/each }}
</ul>
```

When you save them all and run `npm start`, you can see the results at http://localhost:3000

Comment: how to change twitter handle i am using ajax  get   var twitterhandle= $('#twitterUsername').val();
    $.ajax({
type: 'GET',
      data: {        
        text: twitterhandle
              },
      url: '/statuses/user_timeline' ,


  }); kindly share  what i want to add in  /routes/index.js

Comment: Check this part: 
`{ screen_name: 'nodejs', count: 20 }`

You can also get more information from [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline)

Comment: i got your point but i want change twitter handle at run time(like enter your twitter handle & see your tweets) ,  so i added ajax get script in JavaScript file   but i don't know what are changes need to done in index.js file

Comment: Ahh, okay then, let's do it like that:

Replace `'/'` parameter with `'/:handle'` in the get method. And replace `screen_name: 'nodejs'` with `screen_name: req.params.handle || 'nodejs'`.

Now you can use it like http://localhost:3000/gokaygurcan and it'll return the given user's last 20 tweet, or if you don't give any parameter, it'll work as before.

Comment: thanks & i have another query it is not working i don't know why ?           `'var twitterhandle= req.query.text;`
`screen_name:twitterhandle`

Comment: I can't tell anything before seeing the full scope. I just don't know how you're getting that `text` value for example. Just a small reminder, please mark the answer as accepted answer to help others.

Comment: I tried may times to accept as answer but my  reputation is too low that;s why i can't add & here is my code   `$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
      data: {        
        text: bla 
              },
      url: '/statuses/user_timeline' ,
success: function(response) {`

Comment: In your router file, change your get method's first parameter as `/statuses/user_timeline` (the same url that you are calling with $.ajax). By this change, you're able to get parameters from the request, so simply replace `req.param.handle` part that I typed above with `req.query.text` (which comes from the data object of $.ajax).

Comment: I have tried this code before getting there, for some reason, it shows tweet from others (perhaps my wall), and not my tweets.